# Equivalent of ClientCredentials in WCF connection from a C# WinForm?

Tags: java, swift, wcf, ksoap2

What's the equivalent of ClientCredentials in WCF connection from a C# WinForm application to an HTTP request in Android Java or Swift?

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };

SvcClient objSvcClient = new SvcClient();
objSvcClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
objSvcClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = txtPassword.Text;

int intout = objSvcClient.GetData(999);
objSvcClient.Close();

MessageBox.Show(intout.ToString());
```

Comment: ClientCredentials enable users to configure client and service credentials and service credential authentication settings for use on communicating clients.

Comment: To whomever downvoted the question without understanding the intent of it. I am trying to use a service that has credential authentication on a mobile app and wondering how to replicate the ClientCredentials part in that C# snippet .

Comment: So don’t you know what values should be assigned to UserName and Password?

Comment: I do. I just don't know how I could emulate the same thing in Java Android using an HTTP library. I usually do a normal connection with a namespace and an action.

Comment: Just add the authorization header to the http request, you can refer to this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276825/how-to-pass-client-credentials-in-postman

Comment: Thanks it worked. Please post it as an answer so I could mark it as best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the authorization header to the http request,for more information about it, you can refer to this link:

[how to pass client credentials in postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276825/how-to-pass-client-credentials-in-postman)